# Hibernate 4.3 transactions in CMT EJB with Glassfish v4

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jta

I'm using Java EE 7 and latest Hibernate 4.3 on Glassfish 4. According to Hibernate documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-demarcation-jta) I created:

pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml in src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">xxx</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup</property>

        <mapping class="xxx" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil helper class

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

and EJB Stateless bean

```
@Stateless
public class AccountBean {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    @Transactional
    public List findAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List accounts = session.createQuery("from Account").list();

        return accounts;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup
>   specified     at
>   org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:85)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)

Only working way is manually starting transactions each time like this:

```
public List findAll() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List accounts = session.createQuery("from Account").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return accounts;
}
```

but I don't want to write it all the time since I don't have to, according to documentation.

Comment: Hi! How did you managed to fix that? I'm having the same problem! Thanks.

Comment: Without HibernateUtil, you can use Java EE to inject EntityManager using @PersistenceContext annotation. And in EJB all methods all transactional by default.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use

```
     <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">...</property>
```

in Hibernate 4. Use something like

```
<property name="connection.datasource">jdbc/MyDB</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">jta</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform</property>
```

Answer (score -1):

dont forget above your EJB:

```
   @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Not an answer, doesn't solve the "No TransactionManagerLookup specified"